# Validation rule for data dependency

Tags: formula, validation

I'm new to coding in Salesforce and I'm trying to code the following logic:

If a certain picklist value is chosen, another certain field cannot be left blank.

I wrote the following but I'm not sure what's wrong:

`IF((ISPICKVAL(Stage,"Lost")), ISBLANK( Reason_Lost))`.

**Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you please try the formula `AND( ISPICKVAL(Stage, 'Lost') , ISBLANK( TEXT(Reason_Lost__c)))`

**EDIT**:updated my answer as you told Reason_Lost field is Picklist

Answer (score 1):

IF(AND((ISPICKVAL(Stage,"Lost")), ISBLANK( Reason_Lost)),TRUE, FALSE)

Comment: I get the error that the field 'Reason_lost' is a picklist field. Is there a function I can use to check if it's empty or not that is the equivalent of 'ISBLANK'?

Comment: IF(AND((ISPICKVAL(Stage,"Lost")), ) ISPICKVAL(Credit_Card__c," "),
TRUE, FALSE)

Answer (score 1):

AND((ISPICKVAL( StageName ,"Closed Lost")), ISBLANK(TEXT(  Reason_Lost__c )))